# Is membership in the Paris Convention for the Protection of Industrial Property required for other special agreements such as PCT?

Tags: intellectual-property, international

I am currently studying for an exam in intellectual property rights and read that the *Paris Convention for the Protection of Industrial Property* is a umbrella agreement, whereas agreements such as PCT (*Patent Cooperation Treaty*) or MMA (*Madrid system for the international registration of marks*) are special agreements (within the umbrella).

Therefore I wonder if **membership in the *Paris Convention for the Protection of Industrial Property* is a requirement for any of the before mentioned special agreements and if not why**?

Special agreements are mentioned in [Art. 19 of the Paris Convention](http://www.wipo.int/wipolex/en/treaties/text.jsp?file_id=288514#P361_57002).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the PCT, yes. Under Article 62 ([PDF](http://www.wipo.int/wipolex/en/treaties/text.jsp?file_id=288637), pg. 47):

> (1) Any State member of the International Union for the Protection of
>   Industrial Property may become party to this Treaty [...]

For the Madrid Agreement, yes. Under [Article 14](http://www.wipo.int/wipolex/en/treaties/text.jsp?file_id=283530#a14):

> (2)(a) Any country outside the Special Union which is party to the Paris Convention for the Protection of Industrial Property may accede to this Act and thereby become a member of the Special Union.

For the Berne Convention, no. I don't see a reason either, as the Berne Convention deals with copyright, while the Paris Convention deals with most other forms of IP. Under [Article 29](http://www.wipo.int/wipolex/en/treaties/text.jsp?file_id=283698#P354_63790):

> (1) Any country outside the Union may accede to this Act and thereby become party to this Convention and a member of the Union. [...]

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I mixed up the relation of the Berne Convention. Of course you are right and it is not a special agreement. Therefore I edited my question so it is not misleading to anyone.